# How to solve Google speech-to-text long_running_recognize error in Cloud Run?

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I'm using google speech-to-text api. When I run this code in Google cloud Run.

`operation = self.client.long_running_recognize(config=self.config, audio=audio)`

I got this error. I searched this error message on google. However I can't fined good answer.

`"/code/app/./moji/speech_api.py", line 105, in _long_recognize operation = self.client.long_running_recognize(config=self.config, audio=audio) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1p1beta1/services/speech/client.py", line 457, in long_running_recognize response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__ return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc) File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')) [pid: 11|app: 0|req: 56/2613] 169.254.8.129 () {44 vars in 746 bytes} [Sat Aug 28 18:16:17 2021] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 19 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 4 headers in 141 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

This is my code.

```
def speech_to_text(request: WSGIRequest):
    moji_response = MojiResponse()
    threads = []

    def transcript_audio_thread(description):
        if description.length == 0: description.status = 'done'
        if description.status != 'done':
            description.status = 'processing'
            description.save()
            if description.api_name == 'amivoice' and description.lang == 'ja-JP':
                description.transcribe_ami()
            else:
                description.transcribe_gcs()
        description.consume_audio_limit()
        description.update_at = timezone.now()
        description.status = 'done'
        description.save()
        description.save_words(description.words)
        moji_response.append(description.get_result_dict())
        send_mail_for_over_10_min(description, description.user)

    def transcribe_gcs(self, gcs_uri, is_long_recognize):
        audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
        logger.info(f'gcs_uri: {gcs_uri} speech.config: {self.config}')
        try:
            if is_long_recognize:
                self._long_recognize(audio)
            else:
                self._recognize(audio)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'recognized file gcs_uri: {gcs_uri} {e}')
            raise e

    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    def set_config(self, language_code, sample_rate_hertz, phrases, channels=1, ):
        logger.info(f'language_code: {language_code} sample_rate_hertz: {sample_rate_hertz} channels: {channels}')
        encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC
        # encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
        self.config = {
            'encoding': encoding,
            'sample_rate_hertz': sample_rate_hertz,
            'language_code': language_code,
            'enable_automatic_punctuation': True,
            'enable_word_time_offsets': True,
            'audio_channel_count': channels,
        }
        if len(phrases) > 0: self.config['speech_contexts'] = phrases

    @stop_watch
    def _long_recognize(self, audio):
        operation = self.client.long_running_recognize(config=self.config, audio=audio)
        logger.info("Waiting for speech_to_text to complete...")
        self.response = operation.result(timeout=60 * 90)

    def transcript_audio(file_path: str, user: CustomUser, language_code: str, api_name: str,
                         is_trial: bool) -> Description
        t = threading.Thread(target=transcript_audio_thread, args=(description,))
        t.start()

        if description.length > 600 and user.plan != 'anonymous':
            moji_response.append({'id': description.pk, 'file_name': description.file.name,
                                  'text': MyMessage.OVER_10_MIN})
            return
        threads.append(t)
```

This error happen only few files. Most of all files can transcript.

**Error file info**

- type: flac
- duration: 1181 seconds
- language: ja-JP
- sample_rate: 16000Hz
- size: 33.7MB
- channels: 1

When I transcript same file and same code in local development environment, it worked fine.

**Authentification**

- ServiceAccount

I downloaded auth json file. Then set the path to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
)
```

This authentification work fine. Because when I transcribe audio files can do it. The error happen only a few files.

Is there anyone help me, how to solve this error?

Comment: Could you provide more details about your scenario (did you create a ServiceAccount, how you are auth it, etc) andmore details about files which work and which fails? How long audio files are and how much MB they have? Is it possible to provide your code? Is there anything specific for those files (audio format?)? Is that full error output? Could you provide all steps to replicate this issue on GCP?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I add some informations.

Comment: To sum up, all issued files are FLAC format? Your file is in GCS, if you run it from your machine it works properly but if you will run code in Google cloud Run it doesn't work. What plugin are you using? Could you specify how exactly are you using this on Cloud Run, you are using CLI?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't explain about this problem. My posted code was not enough to answer this question. However, finally I solved this problem. I added my answer. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Great! Please accept your answer, it won't give you points but it will be more visible for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error. This is not text-to-speech error. It is `threading` error. I forgot append `Thread` before `return`.

```
        t = threading.Thread(target=transcript_audio_thread, args=(description,))
        t.start()

        if description.length > 600 and user.plan != 'anonymous':
            moji_response.append({'id': description.pk, 'file_name': description.file.name,
                                  'text': MyMessage.OVER_10_MIN})
            return
        threads.append(t) <-- point
```

I changed above code like below.

```
        t = threading.Thread(target=transcript_audio_thread, args=(description,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t) <-- point

        if description.length > 600 and user.plan != 'anonymous':
            moji_response.append({'id': description.pk, 'file_name': description.file.name,
                                  'text': MyMessage.OVER_10_MIN})
```

On local environment can run `Thread` after HttpResponse.  However Cloud Run stop server after HttpResponse. So I got this error only in Cloud Run.

```
GET / => generated 0 bytes in 19 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 4 headers in 141 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```